# MAC Terminal: Anyone know how to give text a default background / highlight color?

Tags: macos, fonts, terminal, customization, transparency

**I wish to have a transparent terminal.**

In order the view the letters without increasing the font size, I would like to have a **contrast** by coloring the **text's background**.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Perhaps installing a special font?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use bright colored text. I was just experimenting and it seems like a good, bright red stands out on most backgrounds. You can also experiment with the blur effect your terminal has. A higher blur will allow for more background contrast. I did not see a way to color the text's background color itself though.